# Error in using templated function with template parameter to be templated class

Tags: c++, templates

here is a minimal example

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
struct MyClass{
    T value;
};

template<typename T, template<typename> class Class>
void foo(Class<T>& myClass){
    myClass.value=0;
};

int main(){
    MyClass<double> myclass;
    foo<double, MyClass<double>>(myclass);
    return 0;

}
```

This code will not compile and gives the error

```
 error: no instance of function template "foo" matches the argument list
            argument types are: (MyClass<double>)
      foo<double, MyClass<double>>(myclass);
```

The reason why I want to write a function is that I want to write a function that transfer data between CPU and GPU. The function looks like

```
template<typename Scalar, template<typename > class Host,
        template<typename> class Device>
void copyFromHostAsync(const Host<Scalar> &host, Device<Scalar> &device, cudaStream_t stream) {
    assert(host.rows() == device.rows());
    assert(host.cols() == device.cols());

    cudaMemcpyAsync(device.getPtr(), host.getPtr(), sizeof(Scalar) * host.rows() * host.cols(),
                    cudaMemcpyHostToDevice, stream);

}
```

I want to use the templated class as parameter so that the underlying scalar type is the same.

Any help is welcomed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`foo` is a template function, which takes as template parameter a type `T`, and a template type with 1 argument type `MyClass`.

If you write:

```
foo<double, MyClass<double>>(myclass);
```

The second template parameter is *not* a template with 1 parameter type. It is just a simple type. And because it is a type, not a template type, your code doesn't compile.

Using just `MyClass` will compile, as `MyClass` is a template type which takes 1 template parameter:

```
foo<double, MyClass>(myclass);
```

Also, just let the compiler do the job for you and let it deduce the types:

```
foo(myclass);
```

Comment: That is indeed the case sir! Thank you very much!